# How I get random items from a Given array and using it on another array in C

Tags: arrays, c, random

I am trying to code Water Sort Puzzle game on C for a school project, and I need to randomize the colors of water in bottles. So I was thinking that I create an array for colors that I represent it with characters like 'r' for red, 'y' for yellow etc. and then putting it randomly on a different array like bottles.

````
```C
char colrs[4][3][2]={{"r","y","b"},{"r","y","b"},{"r","y","b"},{"r","y","b"}};
char bottles[20][2]={};


printf("|%c| |%c| |%c| |%c| |%c|\n",glasses[0],glasses[4],glasses[8],glasses[12],glasses[16]);
printf("|%c| |%c| |%c| |%c| |%c|\n",glasses[1],glasses[5],glasses[9],glasses[13],glasses[17]);
printf("|%c| |%c| |%c| |%c| |%c|\n",glasses[2],glasses[6],glasses[10],glasses[14],glasses[18]);
printf("|%c| |%c| |%c| |%c| |%c|\n",glasses[3],glasses[7],glasses[11],glasses[15],glasses[19]);
printf("+-+ +-+ +-+ +-+ +-+");
```
````

My Plan is getting a output similar to this:

```
|r| |y| |r| | | | | 
|b| |r| |y| | | | |
|r| |b| |y| | | | |
|y| |b| |b| | | | |
+-+ +-+ +-+ +-+ +-+
```

I made a lot of research about it but I can't find any solution that works on C whatsoever. Any help would be appreciated. I am new to coding BTW.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are talking about using characters but your code uses strings. Why not `char`? Also, what exactly is your problem? Selecting a random number? How do these entries in `colrs` array map to `bottles` array? What is your expected result? And what have you tried so far and in what way differs it from what you want to get? Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to have a *specific set* of color values presented in random order, use the **Fisher-Yates Random Shuffle** algorithm to mix up the array of colors, then just read the colors from it in order.

But if you just want random colors, just make a function that will give you a random color every time you call it.

```
void get_random_color( unsigned char * red, unsigned char * blue, unsigned char * green );
```

Remember to randomize the RNG exactly *once* before you do anything else:

```
int main(void)
{
  srand( time( NULL ) );
```